# Can I perform GeoIP blocking in NGINX without having to pay for NGINX Plus?

Tags: nginx, geoip

I'm a Fedora 29 enduser looking for a way perform GeoIP blocking via NGINX without having to pay a lot of $$ for Nginx Plus. I saw NGINX can be setup to include modules and wanted to ask if there are any open-source modules that can be used to perform basic GeoIP blocking.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe try compiling with this module? https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html

Comment: @RyanZ that seems to be a spec document, not actual code. I saw a GitHub repo with some C-code but I'm not sure if that would be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build nginx and add the geoip module from nginx https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html by adding "--with-http_geoip_module" to the nginx build configuration.

Then in your nginx.conf you specify geoip_country or geoip_city followed by a path to a geoip db

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-by-geoip/ can also help with setting up geoip for either open-source or nginx plus

**Edit**: GeoIP is deprecated but will still work for existing installs.

You can build GeoIP2 from source here https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module with nginx in a similar manner as before

Here is the newer geoip2 database [Geolite2 Country](https://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLite2-Country.tar.gz)

Comment: I may opt to compile via source. I'd just prefer to install it from a repo for easier updates.

Comment: You'll note that only a few short days after this answer was posted, the geoip Maxmind databases were removed (they've been deprecated for quite a while now). You now need to a) build your own nginx binary/modules with *geoip2* or b) upgrade to nginx-plus, which *includes geiop2*.